# What does the garbage collector do when it collects a dead object?

Tags: lua

Please follow my input comments (using Lua 5.3.2 at [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-lua-online)):

```
local table = {};

local weakvalues = setmetatable(
{
    table
},
{
    -- Let weakvalues values
    -- be weak, so that they fade when dead objects are g-c.
    __mode = 'v'
});

table = _;

-- Now the previously ref. table is unreachable
-- since there are no other references, I think so...

-- Sychronously wait this loop statements
-- in order to execute a next statement (maybe the
-- garbage-collector would have collected the unreachable table above
-- while this loop executes).
for i = 1, 5e7 do end

-- Expected to log 0, but it logs 1. Is the unreachable table
-- still reachable?
print(#weakvalues);
```

I thought the table at `table` would remove `weakvalues[1]` after assigning `table` with `nil`.

Comment: `v` is value. but in your case you need `k` i think

Comment: @moteus `'k'` is for weak keys...

Comment: Sorry. You are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not call collect garbage.
Try this code

```
local t = {}
local weakvalues = setmetatable({t},{ __mode = 'v'})
t = nil
collectgarbage() collectgarbage()
print(#weakvalues);
```

Comment: That means I've to c-g manually, right? Why call it two times, too? It worked with just one call.

Comment: Values with finalizers need two full collection cycles before their memory is reclaimed (on the first cycle their `__gc` metamethods are called, on the second run the memory is freed). It's not needed most of the time (and sometimes it's not sufficient to clean up an "unreachable" object), but it somehow stuck ...